# What are some realtime examples of Exchanger class in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Exchanges class is used when two threads can exchange objects.

I can see in most of example, two threads are started with exchanger object as argument and Exchange is called thereby.

```
Exchanger exchanger = new Exchanger();

ExchangerRunnable exchangerRunnable1 =
        new ExchangerRunnable(exchanger, "A");

ExchangerRunnable exchangerRunnable2 =
        new ExchangerRunnable(exchanger, "B");

new Thread(exchangerRunnable1).start();
new Thread(exchangerRunnable2).start();
```

What are real time situations when this requirement arise during Multithreading? Shall Exchanger class be always used in all cases in Multithreaded project to make project scalable?

**Note**: There is one example found on Google that Producer and consumer may exchange buffers. Not sure how much practical it is. What other practical situations can be so that project can be architect accordingly.Another example is picked from Java documentation but no details are provided

Comment: It's not a very often used class by any means. You are literally swapping information on a single basis which smallers the use case. Many producer and consumer situations work one-directional and not bidirectional like an Exchanger does. "Exchangers may be useful in applications such as genetic algorithms and pipeline designs." - from the JavaDoc and to write GC-less code, see:  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html?z=

Comment: @assoron Thanks. Yes read that also. I am looking for general idea on same, if anyone implemented the same. Basically shall classes be started with exchangers for later stages etc.

Comment: There is an example in the javadoc too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html.  Or on github: https://gist.github.com/hasskell/0e1070d682d487823f01c7dc23a7ece3 or https://github.com/amcereijo/ConcurrencyExamples/blob/master/src/com/concurrency/examples/exchanger/KnockKnock.java or https://github.com/ben-manes/multiway-pool/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/multiway/EliminationStack.java.  And many more.  Just Google ...

Comment: @StephenC: Thanks but it does not give details required. Thanks

Comment: *"What are real time situations when this requirement arise during Multithreading?"* - See the links above for some examples. *"Shall Exchanger class be always used in all cases in Multithreaded project to make project scalable?"*  - No.

Comment: @StephenC: Thanks for response. I can see example like trucks exchanging material etc. But i am not able to visualize. It looks more theoretical. Actually looking for some practical examples if anyone has used in certain condition.